# Flask WTForm CsrfProtect with Nginx/Gunicorn: Referrer checking failed - origin does not match

Tags: python, nginx, flask, csrf, flask-wtforms

I am porting a Django application to Flask, but am hitting this error on my last step: configuring it to run behind nginx/gunicorn. In Django, this threw a similar error message. To get rid of this error in Django you simply added `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to settings, but I cannot find anything comparable in the source code for flask_wtf.csrf

When I fill out a `POST` form and submit it, it fails with `Bad Request Referrer checking failed - origin does not match.`.

Googling that string, I came to the source code of `flask_wtf.csrf.CsrfProtect` [here](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/master/flask_wtf/csrf.py#L215). This is checking the `referrer` against the `host`. Manually executing that code myself, I can see that it compares the host:port of my nginx to the host:port of my gunicorn, and it is failing because my gunicorn port is on a different port than nginx.

Here is the relevant source code in that file, with my comments as annotation

```
# Presumably, good_referrer is Gunicorn, request.referrer is Nginx
# In Django's csrf source code, there is a list of ALLOWED_HOSTS to check against, instead
def protect(self):
    #...
    # If I change WTF_CSRF_SSL_STRICT to false, it doesn't fail
    # But I should be able to check the referrer against a list of allowed hosts
    if request.is_secure and self._app.config['WTF_CSRF_SSL_STRICT']:
        #...
        good_referrer = 'https://%s/' % request.host
            if not same_origin(request.referrer, good_referrer):
                reason = 'Referrer checking failed - origin does not match.'
                return self._error_response(reason)

#... (line 262)
def same_origin(current_uri, compare_uri):
    parsed_uri = urlparse(current_uri)
    parsed_compare = urlparse(compare_uri)

    if parsed_uri.scheme != parsed_compare.scheme:
        return False
    # The hostname includes the host:port
    # This is where I think the failure occurs
    # As Nginx is on a different port than gunicorn
    if parsed_uri.hostname != parsed_compare.hostname:
        return False

    if parsed_uri.port != parsed_compare.port:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: Hello, have you found a viable solution for this?